# Blank solution while creating Xamarin.Forms project on VS 2017 ¿How to add Xamarin Forms without VS template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Hi I'm trying to create a new Xamarin.Forms project from template using Visual Studio 2017, but when I create the project using only an Android, IOS with .NET Standard project I only get an empty solution. How can I fix this? I have already tried to fix it re-installing VS but without success. Any recommendations? I have my Android SDK up to date, also my VS.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Confirm you have Xamarin installed with Visual Studio. Go to the botton of that about page and you should see the different Xamarin.* libraries (Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac)

Answer (score 0):

> when I create the project using only an Android, iOS with .NET Standard project I only get an empty solution

Select `Tools` --> `Extensions and Updates`:

[image]

Select `Online` and search `Xamarin`, download the `Xamarin.Forms.Template`:

[image]

Then, restart VS and try again.